# Angular FlexLayout alignment issue

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to achieve the following layout. [layout desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfwSa.png)

I would like to achieve this with minimal css changes. I believe i am making some mistakes due to my lack of understanding of flex-layout or maybe i have chose the wrong design to implement my goals.
My understanding is the child 1 container should be a column . But each row in that column should align its elements as rows. So i can have some spacing between the "Car Sales Promotion : " and "Car Sale Promotion Id" .

Child 3 container should behave the same way as child 1 but it has many more label:value pairs inside and i would like to group the pairs and have some spacing between other pairs in that row.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is closer to your desired layout, but there are definitely some questions about how you are trying to lay this out. Especially in regards to your rows and that it seems like you are trying to lay out the parts in a table even while you are asking about flex. Hopefully this will at least give you a better starting point.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c422vx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Zachary , thanx for the response as to answer your question.

Comment: I would like the UI to flex....so that each label becomes a row and then the value next row. when i made the screen smaller with your solution i see that the text inputs are overflowing.

Comment: Also....whats the best way to properly align my label:value pairs. I would like them to be centered and align with other label:value pairs. Is that css or i should use flex for that as well ?